# Function $f(2^x)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I make the following function? $f(2^x)=0$ If and only if
 $ x\in \mathbb{N}$

[image]

I have tried to develop this function by $\sin()$ for exampl $f(x) = x \,sin(\frac{\pi\cdot x}{2})$

[image]

But I have not achieved the desired result :(

Comment: You might try moving $x$ to the denominator for the argument of $\sin$.

Comment: precisely what conditions on the function do you want? Also, it looks to me that the graph intersects $y=0$ at way more point than just $2^n$ for $n\in \Bbb N$. Should it be $f(2^n)=0$ iff $n\in \Bbb Z$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cancel out the effect of $2^x$ with $\log_2$, so that you find a function whose roots are precisely positive integers. Define $f(x):=x\sin(\pi\log_2(x))$.

Comment: But isn't $x\sin(\pi\log_2(x))$ also 0 at x= 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 etc. and so fails the "only if" part of the original condition ?

Comment: @gandalf61 Define it to be uniformity $1384$ for $x<1$

Comment: More seriously, there's a (in fact infinitely many) $C^\infty$ function that agrees with that function on $[1,\infty)$, so dodging those zeros is easy if the OP desires it. However, the example graph indicate that such zeros might be okay.

Comment: @gandalf61 I will need to ask precisely what conditions we need to satisfy

Comment: @edm The condition requires $x\in \mathbb{N}$, and -1, -2, -3 etc. are not in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @gandalf61 looking at the given graph, it does not seem so

Comment: Great! Thank you very much :)